# Linux c++ error: undefined reference to 'dlopen'

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I work in Linux with C++ (Eclipse), and want to use a library.
Eclipse shows me an error:

```
undefined reference to 'dlopen'
```

Do you know a solution?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *handle;
    double (*desk)(char*);
    char *error;

    handle = dlopen ("/lib/CEDD_LIB.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    desk= dlsym(handle, "Apply");

    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fputs(error, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    dlclose(handle);
}
```

Comment: I've had this error in a situation different to presented above. The fix was to reorder the `-l` flags. I had to put `-dl` after (in my case) `-ssl` and the error went away.

Answer (score 320, accepted):

You have to link against libdl, add

> -ldl

to your linker options

Comment: I have run into the same problem...
I added the compiler flag under Project>Properties>C/C++Build>Settings>(My Linker)>Miscellaneous in the Linker flags text field. It did nothing.

Comment: Ha, ok, for anyone else that has this problem, use the above path, except go to Libraries rather than Miscellaneous and add the 'dl'

Comment: This answer helped. For anyone who wants to find the location of libdl.so, just go to the root directory and type `locate libdl.so`

Comment: MirroredFate's answer worked for me as well. I don't understand why, though; every other library I've ever had to link worked when placed in Miscellaneous.

Comment: i have added export LDFLAGS='-ldl' before build and it works

Answer (score 112):

@Masci is correct, but in case you're using C (and the `gcc` compiler) take in account that this doesn't work:

```
gcc -ldl dlopentest.c
```

But this does:

```
gcc dlopentest.c -ldl
```

Took me a bit to figure out...

Comment: I've found that the order of the options matters too. On a project using sqlite3, I have to put -ldl (and -lpthread) after -lsqlite3. Don't know what that is, I'm sure the answer is there if I would just RTFM.

Comment: Holy crap, that's it!  I would never have guessed that putting the options first (which makes more sense to me) doesn't work, while putting them after does.  Thank you, @knocte!

Comment: @user2918461 hit the nail on the head. I had to put the -l's in the "correct" order.

Comment: for anyone who is wondering why this is, its because ld reads the libraries left to right then notes any undefined symbols, filling them in when a different library gives them.   the problem being it doesn't check for undefined symbols in the files _before_ the one it is linking

Answer (score 17):

> this doesn't work:
>
> ```
> gcc -ldl dlopentest.c
> ```
>
> But this does:
>
> ```
> gcc dlopentest.c -ldl
> ```
>
> > That's one annoying "feature" for sure

I was struggling with it when writing heredoc syntax and found some *interesting facts*. With `CC=Clang`, this works:

```
$CC -ldl -x c -o app.exe - << EOF
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  if(dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL))
    printf("libc.so.6 loading succeeded\n");
  else
    printf("libc.so.6 loading failed\n");
  return 0;
}
EOF

./app.exe
```

as well as all of these:

- `$CC -ldl -x c -o app.exe - << EOF`
- `$CC -x c -ldl -o app.exe - << EOF`
- `$CC -x c -o app.exe -ldl - << EOF`
- `$CC -x c -o app.exe - -ldl << EOF`

However, with `CC=gcc`, only the last variant works; `-ldl` after `-` (the stdin argument symbol).

Comment: I encounter such problem too. But I don't know why `gcc dlopentest.c -ldl` works whereas `gcc -ldl dlopentest.c` does not. How do you think about it?

Answer (score 17):

I was using CMake to compile my project and I've found the same problem.

The solution described [here](https://bl.ocks.org/kwk/3595733) works like a charm, simply add  ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} to the target_link_libraries() call

Comment: Thanks! This helped me as well. But only after I changed my compiler to clang `SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang++)`. With /usr/bin/c++ on my Ubuntu it was not working... (see also vulcan raven's answer)

Answer (score 8):

The topic is quite old, yet I struggled with the same issue today while compiling cegui 0.7.1 (openVibe prerequisite).

What worked for me was to set: `LDFLAGS="-Wl,--no-as-needed"`
in the Makefile.

I've also tried `-ldl` for `LDFLAGS` but to no avail.

Answer (score 5):

you can try to add this

```
LIBS=-ldl CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing
```

to the configure options

Comment: Using the LIBS variable worked for me to get configure to put -ldl in the right place on the command line.

Answer (score 4):

You needed to do something like this for the makefile:

```
LDFLAGS='-ldl'
make install
```

That'll pass the linker flags from make through to the linker. Doesn't matter that the makefile was autogenerated.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem even using `-ldl`.

Besides this option, source files need to be placed before libraries, see [undefined reference to `dlopen'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183899/undefined-reference-to-dlopen).

Answer (score 1):

In order to use dl functions you need to use the -ldl flag for the linker.

how you do it in eclipse ?

> Press **Project** --> **Properties** --> **C/C++ build** --> **Settings** --> **GCC C++ Linker** --> 
> **Libraries** -->
>   in the "Libraries(-l)" box **press the "+" sign** --> write "**dl**" (without the quotes)-> press **ok** --> **clean & rebuild** your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $gcc -o program program.c -l <library_to_resolve_program.c's_unresolved_symbols>
```

[A good description of why the placement of -l dl matters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894098/6688314)

But there's also a pretty succinct explanation in the docs
From $man gcc

> ```
>    -llibrary
>    -l library
>        Search the library named library when linking.  (The second
>        alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX
>        compliance and is not recommended.)
> ```

```
       It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the
       linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order
       they are specified.  Thus, foo.o -lz bar.o searches library z after
       file foo.o but before bar.o.  If bar.o refers to functions in z,
       those functions may not be loaded.
```

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions(~2.7) of GNU tool chain, glibc did not have direct interface to link loader(dlopen and dlsym functions), so you had to provide -ldl(libdl) at compile time. You don't have to do that anymore with latest glibc version. Just include <dlcfn.h> and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild [openssl](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) (if you are linking with it) with flag `no-threads`.

Then try to link like this:

```
target_link_libraries(${project_name} dl pthread crypt m ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

Comment: Could you explain what this will do?

Answer (score 0):

using cmake for me it helped to put -ldl after ssl to the target:

target_link_libraries(ssl_test
-WL,--start-group
ssl
-ldl
crypto
-WL,--end-group
)