# "undefined reference" when trying to use lp_solve in C/C++ on Linux

Tags: c, static-libraries, linker-errors, undefined-reference, lpsolve

I'm new to linear programming and C. I am trying to use the `lp_solve` library to solve a linear equation. The problem is I can't get [the demo code](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/formulate.htm#C/C++) to work.

As described in [the documentation](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/Build.htm#Statically%20link%20your%20application%20with%20lpsolve), I downloaded `lp_solve_5.5_dev.gz` to my Linux machine. I extracted the files into the same folder as my code and tried to compile:

```
~/Desktop/Code/CA$ cc -o demo demo.c
/tmp/ccpeN8ZV.o: In function `demo':
demo.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `make_lp'
demo.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `set_col_name'
demo.c:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `set_col_name'
demo.c:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `set_add_rowmode'
demo.c:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to `add_constraintex'
demo.c:(.text+0x1e6): undefined reference to `add_constraintex'
demo.c:(.text+0x274): undefined reference to `add_constraintex'
demo.c:(.text+0x29c): undefined reference to `set_add_rowmode'
demo.c:(.text+0x30b): undefined reference to `set_obj_fnex'
demo.c:(.text+0x327): undefined reference to `set_maxim'
demo.c:(.text+0x33b): undefined reference to `write_LP'
demo.c:(.text+0x34e): undefined reference to `set_verbose'
demo.c:(.text+0x359): undefined reference to `solve'
demo.c:(.text+0x383): undefined reference to `get_objective'
demo.c:(.text+0x3a6): undefined reference to `get_variables'
demo.c:(.text+0x3d2): undefined reference to `get_col_name'
demo.c:(.text+0x429): undefined reference to `delete_lp'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I add `liblpsolve55.a` to the command I get the following errors:

```
~/Desktop/Code/CA$ cc -o demo demo.c liblpsolve55.a
liblpsolve55.a(lp_lib.o): In function `scaled_floor':
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x6923): undefined reference to `floor'
liblpsolve55.a(lp_lib.o): In function `scaled_ceil':
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x6f03): undefined reference to `ceil'
liblpsolve55.a(lp_lib.o): In function `set_XLI':
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x7aa2): undefined reference to `dlclose'
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x7bb3): undefined reference to `dlopen'
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x7bd1): undefined reference to `dlsym'
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x7d8a): undefined reference to `dlsym'
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x7da6): undefined reference to `dlsym'
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x7dc2): undefined reference to `dlsym'
liblpsolve55.a(lp_lib.o): In function `set_BFP':
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x7eb4): undefined reference to `dlclose'
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x7fc3): undefined reference to `dlopen'
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x7fe1): undefined reference to `dlsym'
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x831a): undefined reference to `dlsym'
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x8336): undefined reference to `dlsym'
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x8352): undefined reference to `dlsym'
lp_lib.c:(.text+0x836e): undefined reference to `dlsym'
liblpsolve55.a(lp_lib.o):lp_lib.c:(.text+0x838a): more undefined references to `dlsym' follow
................
```

I understand that the `lp_solve` libraries are not loaded in my code. Can you please tell me how I can properly link the `lp_solve` libraries?

Comment: Did you try searching on the web for "undefined reference to `dlsym'
"? You'll find pretty quickly what you are missing.

Comment: Thanks! Learn't that header files contain the declarations and not function definitions. Seems the linker was not able to find the function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing some compiler flags to include the proper libraries. As danielko said, a quick google search on the missing libraries brings up some suggestions. E.g.

[Linux c++ error: undefined reference to 'dlopen'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956640/linux-c-error-undefined-reference-to-dlopen)

http://sourceforge.net/p/dev-cpp/discussion/48211/thread/3bd8b8a1

These suggest your compilation should be something more like:

```
cc -o demo demo.c -ldl -llpsolve55
```

and the [lpsolve documentation](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/Build.htm) suggests a command that includes the project directory such as:

```
cc -I/lp_solve_5.5 -I/lp_solve_5.5/bfp -I/lp_solve_5.5/bfp/bfp_etaPFI -I/lp_solve_5.5/colamd $src -o MyExe.exe -lm -ldl
```

Comment: Although the compile command in your answer was not exact. I am accepting your answer as you did point me in the right direction and thank you for that !  
  
Resolved the math and lp_lib undefined reference using:
cc -o demo demo.c liblpsolve55.a -lm -ldl

Comment: Glad it was at least partially helpful. I run into linker problems like that all the time, and it's always just a task of finding which libraries need to be added.