# Creating binary from executable

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I need some basic understanding,

I have 4 files in this folder

Makefile , libfoo_8_3.so , libfoo_9_3.so , test.c

I compile test.c to make object file test.o and .d file. This Compiles fine

Those two dynamic libraries (libfoo_8_3.so libfoo_9_3.so)are used by my c program
I wanted to make executable.

I am using Makefile, because I needed headers and structures from c files present in the different folder.

I want to make an executable binary, 
when I do something like

```
gcc -fno-builtin-log -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse2 -DMEMS_DEBUG -DMEMS_DISABLED -D__HMAP_64BIT_COMPLIANT_ID_LENGTH__ -DNETOID_LINUX -D_REENTRANT -DXML_BYTE_ORDER=12 -DNX_BYTE_ORDER=12 -DTHIRTY_TWO_BIT -DALLOW_ISERVER_H323 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -DMEMS_DEBUG -ggdb -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/SBC/lib/x86_64 -L/SBC/pkgs_x86_64/def/lib -L/SBC/bin/x86_64 -I(Include many folders) 
-o test test.o 


This gives me following error ->


est.o: In function `main':
/SBC/ser/test.c:33: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/SBC/ser/test.c:35: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/SBC/ser/test.c:50: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/SBC/ser/test.c:52: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/SBC/ser/test.c:68: undefined reference to `tracer_tag_key'
/SBC/ser/test.c:68: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/SBC/ser/test.c:68: undefined reference to `netLogStruct'
/SBC/ser/test.c:68: undefined reference to `NetLogModuleFacilities'
/SBC/ser/test.c:68: undefined reference to `NetLogModuleNames'
/SBC/ser/test.c:68: undefined reference to `NetSyslogSprintf'
/SBC/ser/test.c:68: undefined reference to `netLogStruct'
/SBC/ser/test.c:68: undefined reference to `NetLogModuleNames'
/SBC/ser/test.c:74: undefined reference to `tracer_tag_key'
/SBC/ser/test.c:74: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/SBC/ser/test.c:74: undefined reference to `netLogStruct'
/SBC/ser/test.c:74: undefined reference to `NetLogModuleFacilities'
/SBC/ser/test.c:74: undefined reference to `NetLogModuleNames'
/SBC/ser/test.c:74: undefined reference to `NetSyslogSprintf'
/SBC/ser/test.c:74: undefined reference to `netLogStruct'
/SBC/ser/test.c:74: undefined reference to `NetLogModuleNames'
/SBC/ser/test.c:82: undefined reference to `tracer_tag_key'
/SBC/ser/test.c:82: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/SBC/ser/test.c:82: undefined reference to `netLogStruct'
/SBC/ser/test.c:82: undefined reference to `NetLogModuleFacilities'
/SBC/ser/test.c:82: undefined reference to `NetLogModuleNames'
/SBC/ser/test.c:82: undefined reference to `NetSyslogSprintf'
/SBC/ser/test.c:82: undefined reference to `netLogStruct'
/SBC/ser/test.c:82: undefined reference to `NetLogModuleNames'
```

I need a proper understanding of this , or how can I resolve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956640/linux-c-error-undefined-reference-to-dlopen

Comment: You need to link with libraries that you use.

Comment: I already tried this, @user202729
It gave me the same undefined reference error

Comment: @JesperJuhl 
How can I do that ???

Comment: Read your compilers documentation (hint: for gcc it's the `-l` option, for example `-ldl` for the dlopen bits). Also, I suggest picking up a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thanks @JesperJuhl
-ldl -> all dl errors were removed. 
what about other functions ??

Comment: @Mayank Kataruka - I don't mean to be rude. But, I'm not going to spoon-feed you solutions to every little detail. Do your own research and find out for yourself what libraries provide those other functions.

Comment: @MayankKataruka Such a question is too broad. One question per library please. (also please research before asking)

Comment: Thanks for the help all :)